# Presenting modal view controller from another presented modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, modalviewcontroller

I have a presented view controller that will then present another view controller. The second view controller does not make views beneath it transparent or disable any below views controls. Has anybody ran into this and how were you able to fix it??

```
//view controller for invalid username/password popup
IncorrectPasswordViewController *viewController = [[IncorrectPasswordViewController alloc] init];
viewController.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
viewController.view.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;

//push the modal on the screen
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion: nil];
CGRect r = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - 150,
                      self.view.bounds.size.height/2 - 70,
                      300, 140);
r = [self.view convertRect:r toView:viewController.view.superview.superview];
viewController.view.superview.frame = r;
```

Comment: Any chance of showing us any code?

Comment: Fix what?  You haven't told us what happens...

Comment: There is the code to present the second view controller. This is being done from a view controller that is also a presented view controller.

Comment: I think it is something to do with presenting these view controllers from the sidebar of a split view. Because the first view controller is also not 100% as the app does not make the views behind it transparent as it should. For the first view controller, the transparency issue only happens in portrait orientation (when the sidebar is a presented over the main view) but is correct when in landscape orientation.